# Different image on click Uitableview row

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, uiimageview, uiimage

I having tableview in my application,Since when i click on the row the views open ,contains two image viwer,where two images form two different table  from database,one image viewer showing the image depends on the row clicked,Where as the second one shows the same image for the all rows.Here my code ,

First Image from database,

```
 -(void)Readthesqlitefileforname:(NSString *)brandname
 {  
    sqlite3 *database;//database object
NSString *docpath=[self doccumentspath];
const char *ch=[docpath UTF8String];//string to constant char UTF8string  main part to connect DB

if (sqlite3_open(ch, &database)==SQLITE_OK) 
   {

   NSString *strstmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name,nik,dob,study,phone,mail,fsong,dp from scrap where name = '%@'",brandname];

    const char *chstmt=[strstmt UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;//to execute the above statement
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, chstmt, -1, &sqlstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlstmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            const char *ch=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 0);
            bnnam=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch];
            const char *ch1=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 1);
            urladdr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch1];
            const char *ch2=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 2);
            ydob=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch2];
            const char *ch3=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 3);
            ystud=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch3];
            const char *ch4=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 4);
            yphon=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch4];
            const char *ch5=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 5);
            ymail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch5];
            const char *ch6=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt,6);
            yface=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",ch6];                //NSLog(@"%@",urladdr);
            //const char *ch5=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 4);
            NSUInteger legnth=sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlstmt, 7);

            if (legnth>0) 
            {

                NSData *dt=[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlstmt, 7) length:legnth];
                clsimg=[UIImage imageWithData:dt];//converting data to image
                NSLog(@"image 1 %@",clsimg);
            }
            else 
            {
                clsimg=nil;
            }

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlstmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
 }
```

Second image from database,

```
  -(void)Readsqlitefile
 {
sqlite3 *database;//database object
NSString *docpath=[self doccumentspath];//get sqlite path
const char *ch=[docpath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(ch, &database)==SQLITE_OK) 
    {
const char *chstmt="select * from scrapsign";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, chstmt, -1, &sqlstmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlstmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            NSUInteger legnt=sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlstmt, 0);

            if (legnt>0) {

                NSData *dt=[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlstmt, 0) length:legnt];
                mysign=[UIImage imageWithData:dt];
            }
            else 
                            {
                mysign=nil;
            }

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlstmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
 }
```

Image setting for row click

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

 scrapview *detailViewController = [[scrapview alloc] initWithNibName:@"scrapview" bundle:nil];
 [self Readthesqlitefileforname:[ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 if (clsimg !=nil)
 {
    detailViewController.imgv.image=clsimg;

 }
 [self Readsqlitefile];

if (mysign !=nil) 
{
    detailViewController.imgv2.image=mysign;//second image viewer
    NSLog(@"%@",mysign);

}

detailViewController.txt1.text=urladdr;
detailViewController.txt2.text=ydob;
detailViewController.txt3.text=ystud;
detailViewController.txt4.text=yphon;
detailViewController.txt5.text=ymail;
detailViewController.txt.text=yface;
detailViewController.txt7.text=bnnam;

}
```

while clicking the row the view should show different images on both imageviewer,but only one image view only change on click ,the second showing same image for all the row clicks.
please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: while clicking  the row the view should show different images on both imageviewer,but only one image view only change on click ,the second showing same image for all the row clicks @VakulSaini

Comment: i updated the question ,please check @Stas

Answer (score 0):

add your data before pushing view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

 scrapview *detailViewController = [[scrapview alloc] initWithNibName:@"scrapview" bundle:nil];
 [self Readthesqlitefileforname:[ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

 if (clsimg !=nil)
 {
    detailViewController.imgv.image=clsimg;

 }

 if (mysign !=nil) 
 {
    detailViewController.imgv2.image=mysign;//second image viewer
    NSLog(@"%@",mysign);    
 }

 detailViewController.txt1.text=urladdr;
 detailViewController.txt2.text=ydob;
 detailViewController.txt3.text=ystud;
 detailViewController.txt4.text=yphon;
 detailViewController.txt5.text=ymail;
 detailViewController.txt.text=yface;
 detailViewController.txt7.text=bnnam;

 //now push view controller
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should push your `detailViewController` after set data to its objects. Because `detailViewController` would navigate before getting anything so all objects would be remains same as they were.

and call `[self Readsqlitefile];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method it would update your `mysign`.

But remember one thing it is good if you're doing just practice with `sqlite` other wise saving `UIImage` in `sqlite` is not a good practice your app may be rejected. Never save `UIImage` in database.

Comment: the image is saving in the database,the problem is the second imageviewer is showing the same image for each row click,wher as the first one shows diffrent image.

Comment: because you're not calling `[self Readsqlitefile];` method any where in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` so how `mysign` would be update ?